# How do you input and validate that the days must be 1-30 inclusive?

Tags: javascript

How do you validate that the value are inclusive to 1 and 30, Im trying to calculate the total?

this is what i have:

```
var costs = 80;
var days = 0;
var days =  parseInt(prompt("enter number of days")); 
for (var i = 1; i <=1; i++)
if (days < 1);
{
alert ("total costs is" + days * costs);
}
```

Comment: Simply check whether the number is smaller than 31 and larger than 0? Do you know about relational comparison operators? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Relational_operators . If you are new to JavaScript I suggest to read a tutorial, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/. Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn a new language.

Comment: Yes, I'm new and self teaching. Is there any other sites that you know i could learn from. Also i just noticed that i set var for days

Comment: Have a look at the [javascript tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) under "Learning JavaScript"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this :-**

```
var day = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Number"),10);
var cost = 80;

if(day > 0 && day < 31){
  alert("Total Cost = " + day*cost);
}else{
  alert("Can't you understand English, enter a number");
}
```

**Explanation**

In the first line, a variable `day` will be created with the value provided by the user. `parseInt` is used because, by default, `prompt` returns a string.

The second line defines a variable `cost` and sets its value to 80.

Then the `if` statement checks whether the value provided by the user is more than 0 and less than 31 or not.

If the condition evaluates true, the Total Cost will be displayed otherwise "Can't…number" message will be alerted.

Comment: Thanks this works and does what I want. Also im not studying anything im just interested in learning it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following changes to achieve what you want:

```
var costs = 80;
var days = 0;
var days =  parseInt(prompt("enter number of days"));

if ( !isNaN(days) && days > 0 && days < 31 ) {
    // yes valid
} else {
   // not valid
};
```

`isNaN` is to make sure that the user has in fact given numbers. Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Why are defining `days` 2 times?

Comment: There is no need or `isNaN`, except for clarity maybe. `days > 0` will be `false` if `days` is `NaN`.

Comment: Well @regi want the dates to be btw 1 and 30. Need to ignore cases where the user enters -1 and 30+

Comment: Well the above `if` works in a way that if its a `NaN` don't check if `0 < x > 31`. Also speaking from building large scalable application, checks like this are always best to avoid prod errors, since there are no strong type in JS and typecasting is child's play.

Comment: But knowing how `NaN` works is also important ;) *"and typecasting is child's play"* Not sure what typecasting has to do with that. `NaN` is a number value. `NaN > x` doesn't do any type conversion. Any comparison with `NaN` will result in `false`. That's what's special about `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var costs = 80;
var days = 0;
var days =  parseInt(prompt("enter number of days")); 
days >1 && days < 30 ? alert ("total costs is" + days * costs):alert('Please input a valid number')
```